# Not Sure Which Stats Test to use in SPSS

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have two groups: Students (1) who did and (2) who did not successfully complete an ENG-101 course within two years of taking an ENG-102 course.

I would like to see if there is a difference in their success in ENG-102 (Success = A,B,C; Unsuccessful = D,F,W).

Further, I would like to look at three groups:

(A) Students who successfully completed an ENG-101 course within two years of taking an ENG-102 course

(B) Students who did not take an ENG-101 course prior to ENG-102 but had an ACT waiver (cut-off 26)

(C) students who did not successfully complete ENG-101 within two years of taking an ENG-102 course (No ACT or one < 26).

I would like to see if there is a difference in their success in ENG-102 (Success = A,B,C; Unsuccessful = D,F,W).

Which test would be best to use?

Answer (score 2):

One way to go about solving your first problem would be to define the following two variables for each student:

1. An outcome variable Y such that Y = 1 if the student was successful at completing ENG-102 or Y = 0 if the student was unsuccessful at completing ENG-102;
2. An explanatory variable X such that X = 1 if the student was successful at completing ENG-101 or X = 0 if the student was unsuccessful at completing ENG-101.

Then you could perform a binary logistic regression in SPSS to determine whether the odds of successful completion of ENG-102 are different among students who successfully completed ENG-101 and those who did not.

For your second problem, the outcome variable Y would be defined as above, but the explanatory variable would be defined so that it would have 3 categories - one for each category of students you are interested in. (You could assign numerical codes to each category, such as 1, 2 and 3.) But you could still use binary logistic regression to relate Y to this new explanatory variable. The binary logistic regression model would then allow you to compare the odds of successful completion of ENG-102 among every pairwise combination of groups corresponding to the explanatory variable.

See here for an example of how to perform binary logistic regression in SPSS: http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/MV/Multreg/Logistic-SPSS.PDF.

Comment: Very helpful (+1). Why not use the information in ABCDFW to extend this to ordered logit?

Comment: Thanks, Nick!  Yes, that's possible - it depends on whether Christina is able to implement a more sophisticated model.

Comment: (-1) a) A person new to statistical inference will no doubt be better off with a chi-square test than logistic regression for such a situation in which no covariates are mentioned.  b) A 6-category outcome variable has been truncated into a binary one, with no compensation; that's important to point out.

Comment: @rolando2 The covariate is the group concerned.

Comment: @Nick Cox - I mean there is only one predictor so no need to tackle a multivariate procedure.

Comment: So, what you said is not what you meant; fair enough. I'd still disagree, mainly because logit allows (indeed obliges)  focus on probability of success, the response of interest, whereas chi-square at best confirms or denies an association with incidental information via residuals on what the association entails. Also, I commented, as did you, on using the _ordered_ information  in ABCDFW and there is no scope for that with chi-square, as it ignores ordering. That's not true of ordered logit.  (Side issue: I don't call any procedure _multivariate_ unless the response variable is multiple.)

Comment: @rolando2 Your points are valid, but when I suggested logistic regression I kept at the back of my mind these things: 1) The binary logistic regression set up can easily be expanded to account for the ordinal nature of the original variable, as pointed out by Nick Cox, and/or to include other explanatory variables; 2) The research question formulated by Christina seems a valid question to ask (though it's not the only question one could ask given her data).  Answering research question you are interested in should drive how you are conducting your testing or modeling, not viceversa.

Comment: @rolando2 I was clear in my answer that *one way to solve the problem* is to use binary logistic regression.  I would have preferred it if you would have added your own answer, rather than taking away from mine. This forum should be open to multiple points of view, rather than expect a single poster to provide the most comprehensive answer possible.  Christina can choose, based on her own statistical savvy and her research question, what works best for her.

Comment: If you should downvote answers of mine, I'll be lucky if you take the trouble to explain why, and you'll be successful in that if I then edit my answer to reflect your ideas.

Comment: I'm not used to having people edit what *I* wanted to say, though I understand this is how this forum works. But it helps to remember that people answer questions in their spare time and may not have the time or inclination to provide the most complete or comprehensive answer possible.  We all want to help in some way but there are better ways to help than to make the person who answered feel bad because of how they answered.

Comment: Isabella: You shouldn't feel bad. No-one edited your answer, but comments are allowed! I happen to disagree with @rolando2 here substantively and I wish he'd answer separately in terms of the possibilities and limitations of chi-square, but he has a case and is working entirely within forum guidelines. Also, he did explain his downvote.

Comment: +1 for this post, especially in light of the interesting comment thread.  It would be nice to see some of the ideas that appeared here elevated into the answer itself (hint, hint).